# Accidentally removed ATK package from ASUS FX502VM, keyboard backlight not working, can't reinstall

Tags: laptop, drivers, keyboard, asus-laptop, bloatware

I recently bought an ASUS FX502VM, and it was loaded to the brim with crapware. I immediately downloaded Decrapifier and ran it, and I believe I accidentally removed the ATK package, and now my keyboard backlight isn't functioning.

I initially thought it wasn't a big deal, and attempted to install a new version from the ASUS website, but on running the setup file it tells me that a version has already been installed, and I should uninstall it first from the Programs and Features menu.

However, there is no listed ATK package on the programs and features menu.

I would rather like to get my backlight working!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device Manager and find that device(It should be under Keyboards) and then right click on the device and uninstall it.

Then you can download and reinstall the driver from their website.

Comment: The only device under keyboards is HID Keyboard Device. Is that it?

Comment: @DemiserofD I am really not sure. You should check out this answer https://superuser.com/questions/708043/keyboard-backlight-in-device-manager?rq=1